# rename XML tags using XMLMapper

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson XML mapper in order to turn object into XML

```
ArrayList<Person> temp = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person a = new Person(12);
temp.add(a);

XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.writeValue(path, temp);
```

Person class looks like:

```
public class Person{

private int age;

    public Person(int age){
    this.age = age
    }
}
```

and the XML looks like:

```
<ArrayList>
    <item>
        <age>12</age>
    </item>
</ArrayList>
```

How can I rename the "ArrayList" and "item" tags?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class for the list of `Person`.

```
 // imports used
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

   static class Person {

    private int age;

    Person() {
    }

    Person(int age) {
      this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
      return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
    }
  }

  @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "people")
  static class People {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "person")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Person> getPeople() {
      return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
      this.people = people;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    People people = new People();
    Person person = new Person(12);
    people.setPeople(List.of(person));

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.writeValue(new File("people.xml"), people);

  }
```

The most important thing is this:

```
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "person")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

in class `People`, which is your wrapper class, where you say that you have a list of `Person`, but you don't want to wrap around another set of tags with the sane name.

Also, when you add your wrapper class, the resulting xml tag will be with capitalised `P`( i.e. `<People>`).

So for this situation, we could add before declaring the class the `@JacksonXmlRootElement`, which lets you rename it as you wish (what I did here I just lowered the xml tag to just `<people>`.

Resulting xml:

```
<people>
  <person>
    <age>12</age>
  </person>
</people>
```

Comment: and what should I do if i want to append into the XML file a List of few persons?

Comment: you mean, you are reading a file, read the xml, append people and save it back?

Comment: that seems to be a different question

Comment: I mean, how can you push multiply persons into an XML and keep the wrapper work

Answer (score 0):

Just if incase, someone is in need of something like this..

```
 <onlinebestellung>
   <positionen>
     <artikel>
       <artikelnummer>articleId</artikelnummer>
       <description>"your description here</description>
     </artikel>
   </positionen>
 </onlinebestellung>
```

...you may try this with `jackson`:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "onlinebestellung")
public class OrderTest {
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true, localName = "positionen")
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "artikel")
   private List<Article> position;
}

public class Article {
    private String artikelnummer;
    private String description;
}
```